# independence of infinite collection of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I am reading the book **A First course in Probability** and in the chapter of joint distribution, came through the text **we say that an infinite collection of random variables is independent if every finite subcollection of them is independent.**

How can this statement be proven and how can the finite subcollection be created from infinite collection of random variables since we need to be able to know all the elements in the collection to make all the possible subcollections.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is the *definition* of independence for an infinite collection. It does not need to be proved, we simply call a family of random variables independent if any finite subcollection is independent. That is, if $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ is any collection of random variables and it just so happens that for any $i_1,\ldots, i_n \in I$ we have that $(X_{i_1}, \ldots, X_{i_n})$ is independent in the sense that the joint probability distribution splits as a product of the marginal distributions, then we say that the family  $(X_{i})_{i \in I}$ is independent.

What would probably be your next question is that how could we possibly show that $(X_{i_1}, \ldots, X_{i_n})$ is independent for *any* finite subcollection when it seems to require checking an infinite number of conditions. Much like showing the square of any real number is non-negative, you do not need to have a separate proof for each real number. There is some extra structure that typically allows you to just take an arbitrary finite subcollection and directly show, regardless of which indices were selected, that the finite subcollection is independent.